# Is it safe to store batter/dough that contains eggs?

Tags: food-safety, eggs, dough, pancakes, batter

I sometimes like to make a large batch of pancake butter or cornbread dough, and fry/bake it whenever I want some freshly made pancakes or cornbread. Both these liquids contain eggs. Is is safe to store them in the fridge, so long as they eventually get cooked? Nothing is being consumed raw here.

If so, how long can I reasonably store the batter/dough before things get iffy? I'm wondering about salmonella in particular.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the leaveners may lose the effectiveness over time. That may actually ruin your batter before spoilage.

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can store them in the fridge. When things start to smell bad, you should toss it. From what I remember off hand, every pancake or cornbread batter recipe I've read says about a week is safe.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I've kept pancake batter in the fridge for 3-4 days, because I only make 1-2 pancakes at a time for myself in the morning before classes. I've never had a problem with it, other than a loss of rise. If you are worried about salmonella, I would say just make sure the pancakes are cooked all the way through. http://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/food-poisoning/news/20080611/salmonella-frequently-asked-questions