# How to fix pancakey cookies after substituting yogurt for eggs?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, cookies, texture, buttermilk

I made a cardamom cookie batter using [this recipe](https://www.melskitchencafe.com/gourmet-buttermilk-cookies/) but using cardamom instead of lemon. I had no eggs, so I tried substituting Greek yogurt (non-fat, since that’s what I had). First batch I made have the texture of pancakes. I have the rest of the batter in the fridge and I now have eggs—can I save the batter by adding the eggs now, or is there something else I should do?

Side note: the batter has been in the fridge for about 36 hours. Is it still good to use?

Comment: What a strange circumstance! How much Greek yogurt did you actually substitute? Additionally, are you interested in experimenting to try and recover this, or would you rather lean towards minimizing the risk of ingredient waste?

Comment: I used half a cup of yogurt in place of two eggs. I am willing to experiment!

Comment: There used to be a question on here about what to do with a bad batch of cookies, but I’m not having luck finding it, so it might have been part of the purge of questions that didn’t have ‘only one right answer’.  I think I had suggested making a bread pudding (with no sugar in the custard so it’s not overly sweet), and others had said stuff like crumbling over ice cream.

Comment: If you don't mind, please check back in and let us know how it went!

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a rushed answer since you're on the clock with the batter expiration. My best research at that, not being a food safety expert, [indicates that you can keep it up to about a week, or until it smells off.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19382/is-it-safe-to-store-batter-dough-that-contains-eggs?rq=1)

At a glance, I'd guess that a half a cup of non-fat greek yogurt for two eggs is likely going to be far less fat, which will negatively affect your texture, but more importantly it's not going to produce the same sort of binding reaction that eggs would.

Since you indicated you're willing to experiment, you could try adding the eggs alongside a bit of extra butter to fill in for the missing fat, then a dash of extra flour.

If I had to guess at the quantities, I'd suggest maybe another 1/8 of a stick of butter and 1/4 cup of flour?

What may be a more reliable strategy is, if you *really* have time, to recreate the recipe from scratch properly to get a feel for the intended texture of the batter, then try to adjust your original batter to match similarly by modifying it gradually and carefully.

Good luck, and have fun! :)